# Views - how to create a chart AND a table from the same filter selection

Tags: views, charts

I know how to create a chart using Views and I also know how to create a table. How do I used the same set of filters to create both but on the same page I am looking at?

I have embedded views inside views as well but that doesn't seem to do the job. Anyone got any idea?

Comment: Which module are you using for creating your chart? http://drupal.org/project/charts , http://drupal.org/project/chart or any of the other typical charting modules?

Answer (score 0):

I can do that in the following ways:
a. Create View page to generate table with exposed filter
b. Clone the view page (table), and change the title name and the path
c. Change the cloned page from Table to Chart, set the field for the chart setting to display, then save
d. Open the original table page view, the add footer -> global view -> select the view chart that you created in (b)

Now you have table with filter on top, and the chart below (also with the same exposed filter). The chart follows the results of the filter on the table.
I use CSS to hide the filter for the chart on the footer.